# Why we got 2 warnings for our Azure AD App registration which was created using visual studio

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-identity-platform

I created a new ASP.NET Core MVC 6.0 web application >> and i define it to use Azure AD for authentication, as follow:-

[image]

[image]

then i were asked to create owned application, so i created one named "ad" as follow:-

[image]

[image]

and inside my application's appsetting i got these settings:-

```
{
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "*****",
    "TenantId": "***",
    "ClientId": "***",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc"
  },
```

so seems visual studio did all the work for us. but when i accessed the "ad" application inside Azure >> i got 2 warnings, as follow:-

[image]

so what are those warnings trying to say? and how we can solve these warnings and to use more up to date approach? as we are planning to build a long-life asp.net core application.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Please read the warnings, their explanation is pretty straight forward. And they both contain links to additional information.

A short summary:

1. Don't use ADAL (and Azure AD Graph), use [MSAL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-overview) (and Microsoft Graph).
2. Make sure you're a verified publisher if you want end users to grant consent on newly registered multi-tenant apps.

Both of these warnings have nothing to do with the app registration itself, but with (1.) the authentication framework you're using to build an application and (2.) the way you publish multi-tenant apps.

You can find additional info in the links in the warnings.

Comment: thanks for the reply.. so so the asp.net mvc core authentication we should be fine?